# Eslint configuration error when saving my code

Tags: reactjs

> Error while loading rule 'prettier/prettier': context.getPhysicalFilename is not a function
> Occurred while linting G:\quiz-app\src\index.js

Why is this happening when I have saved my code in vs-code by pressing ctrl+s?

Comment: I had found the solution of that questions/problems . If you face this problem simply reinstall the ESLint by using npm command from terminal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens because eslint-plugin-prettier@4.0.0 is not compatible with eslint@7.11.0 which react-scripts uses and requires an upgrade to eslint@7.32.0.

You'll need to upgrade eslint's version by running `yarn upgrade -R eslint`