# npm start, Failed to compile

Tags: create-react-app, npm-start

I created a new react app with `npx create-react-app my-app2`, and then `cd my-app2`.
But when run this command `npm start`, it shows

> Failed to compile

[image].

And the localhost:3000 shows

> Error while loading rule 'jsx-a11y/alt-text': rule.create is not a function
> Occurred while linting H:\MyApps\my-app2\src\index.js

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Here you ll find your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69424343/eslint-configuration-error-when-saving-my-code

Comment: You're not the only person asking about this today: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69910080/3001761.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting 'node_modules' folder and 'package-lock.json' file. Then run 'npm i'. This worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, Petri. I haven't tried it, because the problem came from  eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y and a latest release has fixed it, so I went directly to install it. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. The latest version 6.5.1 of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y was released 6 hours ago. I installed it, and this problem is solved!

You'll first need to install ESLint:

```
npm install eslint --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add eslint --dev
```

Then, install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y:

```
npm install eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y --save-dev
```

or

```
yarn add eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y --dev
```

Please check the details in https://github.com/jsx-eslint/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y.